# populating spinner in listview and passing spinner values to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I am creating multiple dynamic spinner items from the MySql data and populating them in listview. Everything works fine but when it comes to pass any random spinner data to another activity my code passes value from the last listview item.

here is my listview adapter class to populate multiple spinners in listview

```
 public class ItemListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


List<String> separated_q,separated_p;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private String item,pot,pc,qr;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ItemListViewAdapter(Context context,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   add=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Add);
    resultp = data.get(position);

    List<String> p= new ArrayList<String>();

     separated_q = Arrays.asList(resultp.get(Gtems.sz).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
     separated_p = Arrays.asList(resultp.get(Gtems.Pr).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    for(int i=0;i<separated_q.size();i++) {
        p.add(separated_q.get(i)+" - "+separated_p.get(i));
    }



    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.spinner, p);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    dukannaa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    taadscntu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);



    imgurl = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);


    dukannaa.setText(resultp.get(Gtems.Br));

    taadscntu.setText(resultp.get(Gtems.pr));

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Gtems.IMAGE), imgurl);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
    ViewGroup selectedRowView=(ViewGroup)arg0.getParent();
            Spinner currentRowSpinner=(Spinner)selectedRowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            int selectedPos=currentRowSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

            pc = separated_p.get(selectedPos);
            qr = separated_q.get(selectedPos);



            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Gsingle.class);
            intent.putExtra("qr",qr);
            intent.putExtra("pc",pc);
            intent.putExtra("prn",resultp.get(Gitems.prid));


            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return itemView;
   }
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long  id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();




}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

It works if a single item is populated onto the listview but on populating multiple listview items, only the spinner value from last listview item is passed to Gsingle class. Please suggest where am making the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!!! passed the spinner item position and arraylist to the desired activity and got the comma split and displayed value as per the position of spinner item

here goes the answer

```
  public class ItemListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


 List<String> separated_q,separated_p;
 Context context;
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
  ImageLoader imageLoader;
  private String item,pot,pc,qr;
  HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public ItemListViewAdapter(Context context,
                   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
   this.context = context;
   data = arraylist;
   imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
   }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 return data.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
 return position;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
 }

 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


     inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
add=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Add);
resultp = data.get(position);

List<String> p= new ArrayList<String>();

 separated_q = Arrays.asList(resultp.get(Gtems.sz).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
 separated_p = Arrays.asList(resultp.get(Gtems.Pr).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
 for(int i=0;i<separated_q.size();i++) {
    p.add(separated_q.get(i)+" - "+separated_p.get(i));
 }



ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
        R.layout.spinner, p);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_drop);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


dukannaa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
taadscntu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);



imgurl = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);


dukannaa.setText(resultp.get(Gtems.Br));

taadscntu.setText(resultp.get(Gtems.pr));

imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Gtems.IMAGE), imgurl);

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
ViewGroup selectedRowView=(ViewGroup)arg0.getParent();
        Spinner currentRowSpinner=(Spinner)selectedRowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        int selectedPos=currentRowSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        pc = resultp.get(Gitems.Pr);
        qr = resultp.get(Gitems.Sz);
     xy=String.valueOf(selectedPos);


        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Gsingle.class);
        intent.putExtra("qr",qr);
        intent.putExtra("pc",pc);
     intent.putExtra("xy",xy);
        intent.putExtra("prn",resultp.get(Gitems.prid));


        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});

return itemView;
  }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,   long  id) {
// On selecting a spinner item
   item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();




 }

 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

In Gsingle class

```
 Intent gt=getIntent();

    pc=gt.getStringExtra("pc");
    qr=gt.getStringExtra("qr");
 xy=gt.getStringExtra("xy");
 x=Integer.parseInt(xy);


    separated_q = Arrays.asList(qr.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    separated_p = Arrays.asList(pc.split("\\s*,\\s*"));



     pm.setText(separated_p.get(x));
     qt.setText(separated_q.get(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as to get click button row Spinner and selected index:

```
  @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ViewGroup selectedRowView=(ViewGroup)view.getParent();
    Spinner currentRowSpinner=(Spinner)selectedRowView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    int selectedPos=currentRowSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    pc = separated_p.get(selectedPos);
    qr = separated_q.get(selectedPos);
       intent.putExtra("qr",qr);
       intent.putExtra("pc",pc);
       //... your code here...
       context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: still it takes the value from last listview item. Shall I try creating dynamic ids?

Comment: @user3225075: dear use my code inside onClick method of `add.setOnClickListener` add button

Comment: @user3225075:  and also comment `pc = separated_p.get(selectedPos);qr = separated_q.get(selectedPos);` lines  in onItemSelected

Comment: still it takes the value from last listview item.

Comment: @user3225075: now what problem getting. what position getting in `selectedPos` on add button click?

Comment: first position of spinner item but not the first row